# Is it possible to containerize using docker without a local setup?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a Windows machine and I am just starting to learn docker. I have gone through the internet that the best way to start is by installing docker-desktop.  Is there a way i can use docker remotely on any cloud providers without having to install it on my machine ?
From what I understand I may need to upload my jar files to the remote servers and everything else should be able to be done on the cloud server.
Is there any such subscription I could purchase to use docker remotely ? Please let me know all the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Play with docker [here](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/). If you just started then it is best to install docker on your local machine to get more of a native experience and understanding of docker networks and overlays etc... and after that you can move on to any cloud like aws ECS service, azure etc....